# Append Integer To String Bash Script OSX

Tags: macos, bash, for-loop

I am attempting to write a bash script that loops exactly 20 times and then appends each number in the loop to the variable with a string "group". The output of each variable should be group1, group2, group3, and so on. Unfortunately i am unable to get this to work. Here is my code thus far:

```
   #!/bin/bash

   USERNUM=0
   USERPREFIX='group'

   for (( i = 1 ; i <= 20; i++ ))

   do

   USERNUM=$(($USERNUM+1))

   USERCREATE=$(($USERPREFIX+$USERNUM))

   echo $USERCREATE

   done
```

I am trying to run this script under OSX 10.6. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
USERCREATE="$USERPREFIX$USERNUM"
```

Comment: @user1227118 to expand a bit on IV-A's correct answer, shell vars use '+' for addition not concatenation, so to concatenate 2 value together into 1 string, just 'put them next to each other', as you see above. Good luck to all.